# How to listen on jquery programmatically triggered click

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, triggers

I have the following file upload strategy where I trigger click event on button click on file inputs, but I'm not able to listen on triggered click event. What is the best approach to be able to listen on programmatically triggered click

```js
$('#add-attachment').on( 'click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $fileList = $('#file-list'), attachementMarkup = '<li><input type="file" class="file"><span class="remove"></span></li>';
  $(attachementMarkup).find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');

  //get the value of triggered file input
  $('body').on('click', 'input.file', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-attachment">Add files</button>

<ul id="file-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues:

- your `input.file` `click` event is wired *after* you attempt to invoke it.  Move the click event handler outside the other click event handler (don't nest event handlers)
- your body.on(click) won't fire as your file input is not attached to the body
- the console log will be blank, depending on browser, for browser security reasons

```js
// get the value of triggered file input
$('body').on('click', 'input.file', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
})

$('#add-attachment').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fileList = $('#file-list');
  var attachementMarkup = '<li><input type="file" class="file"><span class="remove"></span></li>';
  var li = $(attachementMarkup).appendTo(fileList);
  li.find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-attachment">Add files</button>

<ul id="file-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#add-attachment').on( 'click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $fileList = $('#file-list'), attachementMarkup = '<li><input type="file" class="file"><span class="remove"></span></li>';
  $(attachementMarkup).find('input[type="file"]').click();

  //get the value of triggered file input
  $('body').on('click', 'input.file', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-attachment">Add files</button>

<ul id="file-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Are you sure is working? do you see some output in console. I just tried your snippet but does not seems to work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  It's not obvious what change you've made or why this would have any effect (hint: `.click()` is the same as `.trigger("click")`).   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: so Your issue is not related ot the click not getting triggered 
Your  'attachementMarkup' variable contanins a html string that is not found anywhere.

Hence it doesnt work.